# Nested routing in react -router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Provider store = {store}>
    <Router history = {history} >
       <section>
            <HeaderWithRouter>
                <Route exact path = "/admin" component={Admin}/>
                <Route exact path = "/deal" component={FormDeal}/>
                <Route exact path="/chart" component={Mycharts}/>
                <SubHeaderWithRouter>
                    <Route exact path="/dealview" component={FinalTable}/>
                    <Route exact path = "/mandate" component={Mandate}/>
                </SubHeaderWithRouter>  
            </HeaderWithRouter>
            <Footer/>
       </section>
  </Router>
  </Provider>
```

I need to render `SubHeaderWithRouter` only for the sub routes specified inside it i.e `FinalTable` and `Mandate`. 
Currently `SubHeaderWithRouter` is rendered for every route.

Comment: I don't really understand your question!

Comment: see @cdaiga if my route is /admin then i dont want SubHeaderWithRouter to get rendered. i want to render SubHeaderWithRouter only for /dealview and /mandate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the regex path for which you want to render the `SubHeaderWithRouter` component

```
<Provider store = {store}>
    <Router history = {history} >
       <section>
            <HeaderWithRouter>
                <Route exact path = "/admin" component={Admin}/>
                <Route exact path = "/deal" component={FormDeal}/>
                <Route exact path="/chart" component={Mycharts}/>
                <Route path="/(dealview|mandate)" component={SubHeaderWithRouter}/>
            </HeaderWithRouter>
            <Footer/>
       </section>
  </Router>
```

and then inside it, specify the actual `Routes` like

```
render() {
    return (
         <div>
             {/*other things*/}
             <Route exact path="/dealview" component={FinalTable}/>
             <Route exact path = "/mandate" component={Mandate}/>
         </div>
     )

}
```